# Defining a member function of an object

Tags: javascript

I declare the following object :

```
var Node = {
  nodeID: '',
  parentID: '',
  nodeName: '',
  children: []
}
```

and I'd like to write a `Contains()` function to check if the `children` array contains a specific `Node` object, used like `Node.Contains(otherNode)`.

Where and how should I declare it to be able to use this syntax ?

Comment: Just put a function as another property of the object. They're not "members" in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare this function next to the other properties:

```
var Node = {
  nodeID: '',
  parentID: '',
  nodeName: '',
  children: [],
  Contains: function(otherNode) {
    return this.children.indexOf(otherNode) > -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm very inexperienced with js and don't know the syntaxes

Comment: @Saryk If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it.

Comment: I was waiting for the delay to be over ;)